# AngularJS send POST Request to server-side script

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, post

I'm building a webapp with yeoman tools using AngularJS, and am having trouble sending a POST request to a server side script from a controller. Here is the function in my controller code:

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
  $http.post('addUser.php', $scope.user).success(function(response) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(response);
    $scope.showForm = false;
    $scope.infoSubmitted = true;
  }).error(function(err){
    console.log('failure');
    console.log(err);
  });

};
```

The addUser.php file is located in the app/ directory, along with index.html. I am a little confused as to how AngularJS handles routing, as well. I know that I can define routes for GET requests in the app.js file with `.when({ ... })`, but I can't see how to handle POST requests and call server side scripts.

This is the .php file I want to connect to:

```
<?php

$errors     = array();    // array to hold validation errors
$data       = array();    // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
if (empty($_POST['name']))
$errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
$errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

// return a response ===========================================================

// response if there are errors
if ( ! empty($errors)) {

// if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

// if there are no errors, return a message
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you added full information about the error (from Firebug or equivalent); then maybe even the php file.

Comment: try throwing a "/" before the addUser.php.  Are you seeing the post request in dev tools?

Comment: This is the error in Dev tools: `POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/addUser.php 404 (Not Found)`. This was the same before I added a "/" before "addUser.php"

Comment: can you use a tool like postman and see if you can post a request to addUser.php?  That should help determine if the problem is client or server side.

Comment: I ended up using the generator-angular-fullstack which provides a file for inputting routing information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put addUser.php to the subfolder - /app/server/addUser.php and do
    $http.post('server/addUser.php', $scope.user)...
Also php files will not work with default generator-angular. You need [generator-angular-php](https://github.com/amercier/generator-angular-php).